# How to emit dbus signal from command line

Tags: linux, dbus

Is there a way to emit dbus signal from command line using dbus-send or something else ?

Comment: checkout `dbus-send` commnand

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the utility `dbus-send` to send D-Bus request from the command line.

```
dbus-send --system --type=signal / com.example.signal_name
```

or if you'd like to send some data with the signal

```
dbus-send --system --type=signal / com.example.signal_name string:"hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [qdbus](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/qdbus.1.html).  There is a decent tutorial [here](http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/609).

Comment: The link to the tutorial is no longer valid